# Claims involving personal information about notable people - Part2 (7 years later)

Tags: discussion, notability, closed-questions, deleted-questions

1. So what's the verdict here? [Claims involving personal information about notable people](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/claims-involving-personal-information-about-notable-people) about https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31738/has-emma-watson-stated-or-been-credibly-reported-to-have-adhd which was indeed Reopened by Jamiec♦ on Feb 13, 2016 at 16:51 but deleted on Mar 12, 2016 at 0:31
2. What's wrong with this?

> If she's addressed it herself, we can write an answer. If she hasn't, it will likely go unanswered, and that is okay

It sounds like a devil's proof dilemma. If there was a clear sourced article such as an interview or something that says Emma Watson has ADHD, then the question is kinda on-topic but probably wouldn't be asked in the 1st place at least if the article is easily searchable. Similar to how no one would really ask if Simone Biles has ADHD. But then because there aren't clear searchable sourced articles, the question is off-topic? I thought the whole point of asking is PRECISELY if there aren't clear searchable sourced articles. **So the on-topic-ness of a question depends on its answer? Seems kinda circular.**

Comment: Does a celebrities personal medical history really need to be brought up on this site when it has nothing to do with what they do? Would knowing if she has ADHD impact her ability to do her job as an actor?

Answer (score 8):

- This appears to be a duplicate of your previous question. What has changed?
- You got what you wanted. Your question was reopened by a mod. It was left unanswered. Then after about 5 weeks, a bot notice that it was downvoted (+5 up votes, -7 downvotes) by the community and had no (surviving) answers, so the bot cleaned it up automatically. Looks like your question was implicitly answered: no-one found evidence that she wrote about it herself.
- Why are you bringing up other unrelated arguments on other sites here?

Comment: 1 - that wasn't mine 2- 'You got what you wanted. Your question was reopened by a mod.' --> oh i totally missed that. lol. thanks. so how do i get it reopened?

Comment: @BCLC You can't, now: it's been deleted. You could ask it again, I suppose, but per community consensus it'd probably be rejected again. (I'd recommend against asking it again.)